# CartThrob Processing Without Required Email

Tags: ee2, cartthrob, forms

I've set up a checkout form that requires the email address field, but users are able to submit the form without an email address, anyway.

Here is my tag, and the fields match up properly:

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form return="give/donation_thanks/" required="first_name|last_name|email_address"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

ty

Answer (score 2):

NM

The problem turned out to be an older version of the form on the site that didn't have the required parameter in place that someone had bookmarked.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why I have to wait two days to accept my own answer.